# Flowers bend down - anything I can do?

Tags: flowers

planted a lot of bulbs and when they flower - pretty much all of them fall to the ground. 
Was wondering if I can do anything to make them grow up and straight? Anything that I’m missing?

For the context - I’m in Sydney, Australia, it’s early spring here.

[image: fallen1]

[image: fallen2]

Comment: Has it been windy/dry/both recently?

Comment: I get this when soil nitrogen is too low. Your lawn looks happy, but fertilizer?

Comment: Yes, it was both windy and dry. We had a very dry winter this year. Never thought about it this way. Although some other plants are just fine. Maybe the planting depth is another factor too.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how deep you planted the bulbs; Freesias need to be planted at a depth of 2 inches, in good, fertile soil, in sun/part shade or full sun. Many bulbous plants fall over when in bloom if they have not been planted at the right depth. Other causes can be weather conditions, extremely windy weather for instance.

Comment: That makes sense. It was windy and unusually dry winter. Also we most likely planted the bulbs at the wrong depth. Now this is exactly what I was looking for from this forum - perfect outcome - something to pay more attention to next time we plant them. Cheers!